# class that extends AbstractGoogleJsonClient constructor expecting Builder, rather than 5 params

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio

from Android Developers  Tic Tac Toe client (Android), https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android 
there is....

```
public class Tictactoe extends AbstractGoogleJsonClient { etc}
```

with the constructor:

```
public Tictactoe(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory,
      HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {


    super(transport, jsonFactory, DEFAULT_ROOT_URL, DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH, httpRequestInitializer
       , false);
  }
```

I get compile errors on the super(), and I'm told that super expects Builder, not the 6 params,

BUT the class Tictactoe extends has a constructor that takes the 6 arguments.

(see
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/json/AbstractGoogleJsonClient.java?r=32555da5a2e95a90154f278184f3be9e230486b3 )

for

```
  protected AbstractGoogleJsonClient(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory,
  String rootUrl, String servicePath, HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer,
  boolean legacyDataWrapper) {
super(transport, httpRequestInitializer, rootUrl, servicePath, newObjectParser(
    jsonFactory, legacyDataWrapper));
```

}

So...

What's happening here?  Why does 'super' expect Builder rather than the 6 args?